# 2-split of $n$ is $\left\{ \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor,\lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil \right\}$. What about 3, 4, ...?

Tags: integers, ceiling-and-floor-functions, integer-partitions, set-partition

Clarification: $k$-split of $n$ is an ordered integer sequence $\left\{ a_1,\cdots,a_k \right\}\quad \text{s.t.}$

- $0\le a_1\le\cdots\le a_k$
- $a_1+\cdots+a_k=n$
- ${\left(a_k-a_1\right)}$ is minimized.

---

I know that

$$
n = \lfloor \frac{n}{3} \rfloor + \lceil \frac{2n}{3} \rceil,
$$

so I guess 3-split of $n$ is

$$
n = \lfloor \frac{n}{3} \rfloor + \lfloor \frac{\lceil \frac{2n}{3} \rceil}{2} \rfloor+\lceil \frac{\lceil \frac{2n}{3} \rceil}{2} \rceil ?
$$

If so, can this be simplified?

Comment: could you please define what a "2-split" is, and more generally what an "n-split" is? It it supposed to be a sequence of $n$ consecutive integers which add to $n$?

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Sorry. I proposed it intuitively. In general I think $k$-split of $n$ is $\left\{ a_1,\cdots,a_k \right\}\quad \text{s.t.}\quad$ (1) $a_1\le\cdots\le a_k$ (2) $a_1+\cdots+a_k=n$ (3) $\sum_{i<j}{a_j-a_i}$ is minimized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is clear your question is satisfied by the following partition:

$$x = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\bigg\lfloor\frac{x+k}{n}\bigg\rfloor$$

Comment: The partition formula is amazing. How should I understand it properly, or if not, prove it?

Comment: @SneezeFor16Min You can think of it as splitting up the possible cases mod $n$

Comment: It's not that obvious to me that possible cases $\mod n$ make up $x$...

Comment: There're some mistakes in the derivations, e.g., $3$-split should be $\big\lfloor \frac{x}{3}\big\rfloor +\big\lfloor \frac{x+1}{3}\big\rfloor +\big\lceil \frac{x}{3}\big\rceil$; $4$-split should be $\big\lfloor \frac{x}{4}\big\rfloor +\big\lfloor \frac{x+1}{4}\big\rfloor +\big\lceil \frac{x-1}{4}\big\rceil +\big\lceil \frac{x}{4}\big\rceil$; $5$-split should be $\big\lfloor \frac{x}{5}\big\rfloor +\big\lfloor \frac{x+1}{5}\big\rfloor +\big\lfloor \frac{x+2}{5}\big\rfloor +\big\lceil \frac{x-1}{5}\big\rceil +\big\lceil \frac{x}{5}\big\rceil$; $\cdots$

Comment: @SneezeFor16Min you are right, I had some mistakes. Not sure what happened... I must have had an error in the code I wrote to check them. I removed them accordingly, though the initial partition should be fine.